# How can I make local changes to node.js library?

Tags: node.js, npm

I installed some node.js package via `npm` (specifically, `sqlite3`). Now I want to add some logging to it's C++ code. I need package to be rebuilt. I tried 'npm edit', but it finishes with errors after 'wq':

```
npm ERR! weird error 1
npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

But I don't want use `vi` or another terminal editor for this. After modifications, I do `npm rebuild sqlite3`. But it does't rebuild anything! How can I modify packages I have locally?

```
[sqlite3]: Sweet: "node_sqlite3.node" is valid, node-sqlite3 is now installed!
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

sqlite3 module has changed normal build process, npm build will execute 'node build.js'. You can read `node_modules/sqlite3/package.json` to know how it is built:

```
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "install": "node build.js",
    "pretest": "node test/support/createdb.js",
    "test": "mocha -R spec --timeout 200000"
  },
```

If you change your C/C++ code, you can rebuild it using node-gyp

```
$ cd node_modules/sqlite3
$ node-gyp rebuild
```

Other option is removing the line `"install": "node build.js"` from `package.json` then call `npm rebuild` again

Comment: Great! Thank you. I solved the problem. I just run `make` from `node_modules/sqlite3` and I'm all set. Internally, it runs `npm install --build-from-source`.